# Optimizing finding a string that matches the characters in a substring in any order?

Tags: python, string, time-complexity, substring, python-itertools

Assuming a list as follows:

```
list_of_strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'soap', 'sseo', 'spaseo', 'oess']
```

and a sub string

```
to_find = 'seos'
```

I would like to find the string(s) in the `list_of_strings` that:

1. Have the same length as `to_find`
2. Have the same characters as `to_find` (irresepective of the order of the characters)

The output from the `list_of_strings` should be `'sseo', 'oess']` (since it has all the letters from `to_find` & all have a length of 4)

I have:

```
import itertools
list_of_strings = [string for string in list_of_strings if len(string) == len(to_find)]
result = [string for string in list_of_strings if any("".join(perm) in string for perm in itertools.permutations(to_find))]
```

To find how long does it take to run the code I did

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit("[string for string in list_of_strings if any(''.join(perm) in string for perm in itertools.permutations(to_find))]", 
              setup='from __main__ import list_of_strings, to_find', number=100000)
```

The process takes a while to give the output. I am guessing it is because of the use of `itertools.permutations`.

Is there a way I can make this code more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. In your comment, you say, "(since it has all the letters from to_find & all have a length of 3)" but it seems they all have a length of 4

Comment: @Nick thanks for pointing it out. It was a mistake. I updated it to 4

Comment: Should `sooe` match?

Comment: No, `sooe` shouldn't because the characters are 'seos'

Comment: OK, just wanted to clarify

Comment: We can split the substring into list using `str1 = [str for str in substring]` and the convert it to set with `strset = set(str1)` and then equate the set of substring since set does not have a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order doesn't matter, you can just sort the strings and compare the resulting lists:

```
list_of_strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'soap', 'sseo', 'spaseo', 'oess']
to_find = sorted('seos')
matches = [word for word in list_of_strings if sorted(word) == to_find]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work because `Counter` creates a dict-like that counts the number of characters in each string and the aim is to match the letters and their counts irrespective of their orders.

```
from collections import Counter
to_find_counter = Counter(to_find)
# go through the list and check if the Counter is the same as the Counter of to_find
[x for x in list_of_strings if Counter(x)==to_find_counter]
['sseo', 'oess']
```